# Is an RPM already installed? Binary compare

Tags: linux, rpm

At my current place of work we sometimes receive a bundle of RPMs and are told to update our environment. The entity providing us the updates is very slack with their processes and sometimes make changes to a package without updating any version number etc. So we have to blindly install whatever they give us (which can take a long time).

eg: Sometimes we have abc-1.2.3.rpm installed and then get a new abc-1.2.3.rpm that contains fixes but has the exact same version numbers! Yes. Its stupid, but we have to deal with it.

Is there a way of knowing if a particular RPM file matches one that is currently installed? Via MD5SUM, SHA1 or binary diff etc?

To solve this problem we copy all of the RPMs that are installed in a particular directory in our system and then do a binary file compare between them and any new files that come (if they have matching filenames). If the binary compare shows different, then we install that RPM and also move the RPM file to that 'installed' directory (for future comparison)

There MUST be a better way to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On first glance, you might consider something based on rpm --verify, but that doesn't allow you to ask 'are the installed files the same as in this RPM file?', rather it asks 'are the installed files the same as listed in the RPM database [of installed packages]'

However, you could conceivably write a script to do a similar thing based around 'rpm --query --dump --package some.rpm', which would output the filenames (with MD5), which you could then check.

Ideally, it seems that the packager really needs to use the Release field.

Comment: With help from you comments I narrowed it down to to:  `rpm -Vp --nomtime some.rpm`.  This command compares the 'digest' of the package contents with what is currently installed it seems (ignoring the mtime field).  However, some packages still show as different even when they're not only because they've been modified as part of the runtime behaviour or the system (false negative). So maybe my dumb way of doing it is the most reliable.

Comment: You probably need to tell it to ignore %config files. From rpm(8): "The format of the output [of rpm -V] is a string of 8 characters, a possible attribute marker: .... 'c' %config configuration file. ..." So you should be able to grep -v items with the 'c' flag in the output.

Comment: A lot of the differences are with the digest column which usually shows the marker '5' showing '?' instead. After digging through the man page I noticed this may be permission related, so doing `sudo rpm` fixes it and reduces the differences significantly.